# regex multiple pattern with singular replacement

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I am trying to replace both "st." and "ste." with "st".  Seems like the following should work but it does not:

```
require("stringr")
county <- c("st. landry", "ste. geneveve", "st. louis")
str_replace_all(county, c("st\\.", "ste\\."), "st")
```

Comment: @TylerRinker Can't you tell from the underscores? ;-)

Comment: I can but wanted to make it more explicit.  I've actually picked up this Wickham habit myself. :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `|` to mean "or"

```
> str_replace_all(county, "st\\.|ste\\.", "st")
[1] "st landry"   "st geneveve" "st louis"
```

Or in base R

```
> gsub("st\\.|ste\\.", "st", county)
[1] "st landry"   "st geneveve" "st louis"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> A<-"this string,  contains a handful of,  useless:  punctuation.  Some are to escape.  Aaargh! Some might be needed,  but I want none!"
> gsub(", |: |\\. |!","",A)
[1] "this string contains a handful of useless punctuation Some are to escape Aaargh Some might be needed but I want none"
```

Comment: Try `gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", A)` for this case.