# Clean string using gsub and multiple conditions

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I already saw this one, but it is not quite what I need:

- [regex multiple pattern with singular replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320595/regex-multiple-pattern-with-singular-replacement)

**Situation:** Using `gsub`, I want to clean up strings. These are my conditions:

1. Keep words only (no digits nor "weird" symbols)
2. Keep those words separated with one of (just one) `' - _ $ .` as one. For example: `don't`, `re-loading`, `come_home`, `something$col`
3. keep specific names, such as `package::function` or `package::function()`

So, I have the following:

1. `[^A-Za-z]`
2. `([a-z]+)(-|'|_|$)([a-z]+)`
3. `([a-z]+(_*)[a-z]+)(::)([a-z]+(_*)[a-z]+)(\(\))*`

**Examples:**

If I have the following:

```
# Re-loading pkgdown while it's running causes weird behaviour with # the context cache don't
# Needs to handle NA for desc::desc_get()
# Update href of toc anchors , use "-" instead "."
# Keep something$col or here_you::must_stay
```

I would like to have

```
Re-loading pkgdown while it's running causes weird behaviour with the context cache don't
Needs to handle NA for desc::desc_get()
Update href of toc anchors use instead
Keep something$col or here_you::must_stay
```

**Problems:** I have several:

A. The second expression is not working properly. Right now, it only works with `-` or `'`

B. How do I combine all of these in a single `gsub` in R? I want to do something like `gsub(myPatterns, myText)`, but don't know how to fix and combine all of this.

Comment: Try `trimws(gsub("(?:\\w+::\\w+(?:\\(\\))?|\\p{L}+(?:[-'_$]\\p{L}+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\\p{L}\\s]", "", myText, perl=TRUE))`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UEghUj/1).

Comment: That works like a charm! Can you please put it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```r
trimws(gsub("(?:\\w+::\\w+(?:\\(\\))?|\\p{L}+(?:[-'_$]\\p{L}+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\\p{L}\\s]", "", myText, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UEghUj/1/). Or, to also replace multiple whitespaces with a single space, use

```r
trimws(gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", gsub("(?:\\w+::\\w+(?:\\(\\))?|\\p{L}+(?:[-'_$]\\p{L}+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\\p{L}\\s]", "", myText, perl=TRUE)))
```

**Details**

- `(?:\w+::\w+(?:\(\))?|\p{L}+(?:[-'_$]\p{L}+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)`: match either of the two patterns:

  - `\w+::\w+(?:\(\))?` - 1+ word chars, `::`, 1+ word chars and an optional `()` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `\p{L}+`  - one or more Unicode letters
  - `(?:[-'_$]\p{L}+)*` - 0+ repetitions of `-`, `'`, `_` or `$` and then 1+ Unicode letters
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omits and skips the match
- `|` - or
- `[^\p{L}\s]` - any char but a Unicode letter and whitespace

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/D35itX):

```r
myText <- c("# Re-loading pkgdown while it's running causes weird behaviour with # the context cache don't",
"# Needs to handle NA for desc::desc_get()",
'# Update href of toc anchors , use "-" instead "."',
"# Keep something$col or here_you::must_stay")
trimws(gsub("\\s{2,}", " ", gsub("(?:\\w+::\\w+(?:\\(\\))?|\\p{L}+(?:[-'_$]\\p{L}+)*)(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\\p{L}\\s]", "", myText, perl=TRUE)))
```

Output:

```r
[1] "Re-loading pkgdown while it's running causes weird behaviour with the context cache don't"
[2] "Needs to handle NA for desc::desc_get()"                                                  
[3] "Update href of toc anchors use instead"                                                   
[4] "Keep something$col or here_you::must_stay"
```

Comment: Now that's a pattern ++

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```r
txt <- c("# Re-loading pkgdown while it's running causes weird behaviour with # the context cache don't", 
         "# Needs to handle NA for desc::desc_get()",
         "# Update href of toc anchors , use \"-\" instead \".\"", 
         "# Keep something$col or here_you::must_stay")
expect <- c("Re-loading pkgdown while it's running causes weird behaviour with the context cache don't",
            "Needs to handle NA for desc::desc_get()",
            "Update href of toc anchors use instead",
            "Keep something$col or here_you::must_stay")

leadspace <- grepl("^ ", txt)
gre <- gregexpr("\\b(\\s?[[:alpha:]]*(::|[-'_$.])?[[:alpha:]]*(\\(\\))?)\\b", txt)
regmatches(txt, gre, invert = TRUE) <- ""
txt[!leadspace] <- gsub("^ ", "", txt[!leadspace])
identical(expect, txt)
# [1] TRUE
```